# How to create a Generic Stack pop method in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, stack

I am currently working on a Stack project where I am creating a generic Stack class. I've been looking on stack overflow for this, but couldn't find it. I need help creating a pop method in my code.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Stack<E>
{
public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private E [] elementData;
private int size;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Stack()
{
    this.elementData = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Stack(int capacity)
{
    if(capacity < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity " + capacity);
    }
    this.elementData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
/*
The push method should add its parameter to the top of the stack.
*/
public void push(E item)
{
    ensureCapacity(size+1);
    elementData[size] = item;
    size++;
}
private void ensureCapacity(int capacity)
    {
    if(elementData.length < capacity)
    {
        int newCapacity = elementData.length * 2 + 1;
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    }
}
```

I need help right here. I need to have the pop method remove and return the element at the top of the stack. If no items
are present, it should throw an "EmptyStackException".

```
    public E pop()
    {
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        throw EmptyStackException
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: With your implementation, the top element will always be the last inserted element in your array. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Your `pop` should be the opposite of your `push`

Comment: @ScaryWombat the only thing is, what do I replace with item?

Comment: why do you need to replace?  Just decrement `size`

Comment: @ScaryWombat  item is not in the pop method, so if I'm doing the opposite of push, where would item stand?

Comment: It is contained at `elementData[size - 1]`  you can set to a local variable and return it, or simply just return it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you! It works. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I give the credit to @ScaryWombat. The code is:

```
public E pop()
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    else
        {
            return elementData[--size];
    }

}
```

Comment: This answers everything! Thank you @ScaryWombat

Answer (score -1):

```
public E pop()
 {
    E item;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    else
    {
        item = elementData[size];
        size--;
    }
    return item;
}
```

You need to make your return variable equal to the top of your stack array and then decrement your stack array. Also, you need to initialize your stack by setting size=0.

Comment: *you need to initialize your stack.* - what do you mean? What is wrong with the Constructors?

Comment: Also you want to decrease `size` first

Comment: My apologies for not being more specific... my first time trying to help out.

Comment: Yeah, he does want to decrease size first, sicne he already inceased it on the push.